# Android Room Exceptions

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java, reactive-programming, android-room

What kinds of exceptions I should consider while working with Android Room.
From my research I found out that there is only one exception that might occur.

[Room Exceptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/package-summary#exceptions)

That is also when you are having `Single<T>` as a return type and you have an empty return. Other than that I couldn't find any other possible scenario that might throw an exception.

Of course, there might be some exceptions if you have some logical incorrect implementations, like

- Editing scheme, but not implementing `Migration`
- Not implementing `OnConflictStrategy` while inserting
- Running Room on Main Thread while not allowing it with `allowMainThreadQueries()`

I did some research and tried out almost all possible cases, mostly with RxJava return types and I saw one exception mentioned above and that's it.

> [Here](https://medium.com/@musooff/rxjava-and-room-complete-guide-sheet-7fca5b49804e) is my tests that I run

I wanted to make sure that I have implementation for every possible scenario and not have some exception and unexpected crashes. I was thinking of occurrences of `SQLite` exceptions might happen, but I believe it's wrapped around Room and it will handle. (Not sure)

Can you give any other possible exceptions that might occur?

Comment: great question, came here asking the same thing...

Comment: This is not well documented for some reason. But I know at least some SQLiteExceptions are thrown by Room. E.g., Room will throw an SQLiteConstraintException if a ForeignKey constraint is violated.

Comment: There is also an exception. That says Database is locked. It is cause if you try to access the database while it is perform any action or other thread is preforming some task.

Comment: If you use the Room Converter and if the converter is not up to date or not created in the right form then the exception can occur.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Android Room, a SQLite database library that simplifies database operations, you should consider handling various exceptions to ensure the reliability and robustness of your app. Room abstracts many database-related complexities, but it doesn't eliminate the possibility of exceptions. Here are some common exceptions you should consider while working with Android Room:

1. `SQLiteConstraintException`: This exception is thrown when you violate a database constraint, such as a primary key or unique constraint. Ensure that your database schema and data insertion/update operations adhere to the defined constraints.
2. `SQLiteException`: This is a general exception for SQLite-related issues. It can occur for various reasons, such as disk I/O errors, database corruption, or exceeding storage limits. Handling this exception is essential to provide a better user experience.
3. `IllegalStateException`: You may encounter this exception when attempting to perform database operations on the main UI thread. Room requires database operations to be performed off the main thread. Use background threads, AsyncTask, or a library like Kotlin Coroutines or RxJava to handle database operations asynchronously.
4. `RoomDatabaseException`: This exception is Room-specific and can occur for various reasons, including issues with database migrations or misconfigured entities and DAOs. Check your database configuration, versioning, and migrations to prevent this exception.
5. `RoomSQLiteQueryException`: This exception can occur when there's an issue with a SQL query you've written manually, typically when using the `@Query` annotation. Double-check your SQL queries and make sure they are syntactically correct and match your database schema.
6. `StaleDataException`: In multi-threaded scenarios, you might encounter this exception when attempting to access data that has been modified or deleted by another thread. Implement appropriate synchronization mechanisms, such as LiveData or RxJava, to handle data concurrency safely.
7. `NullPointerException`: While not specific to Room, null pointer exceptions can occur if you don't handle nullable database queries properly. Always check for null values when accessing data retrieved from the database.
8. `TransactionTooLargeException`: This exception can occur when you try to transfer a large amount of data between activities using Android's Parcelable mechanism. Consider using other methods like ViewModel or shared preferences for passing data between activities to avoid this exception.
9. `SecurityException`: When using Room, you may need to access the SQLite database file directly. Ensure that you have the necessary permissions to access and modify the database file, especially when using external storage.
10. `OutOfMemoryError`: This error can occur if you load a large amount of data from the database into memory without proper memory management. Use techniques like pagination or limiting query results to prevent running out of memory.

To handle these exceptions effectively, consider using try-catch blocks, LiveData, RxJava, or Kotlin Coroutines, depending on your project's architecture and requirements. Proper exception handling will improve the reliability and stability of your Android app when working with Room.